# How secure is my private repository on bitbucket

Tags: project-management, version-control, source-code

Does anybody know how secure are my private repositories on bitbucket.org? Can I rely on that?

I have some repositories and I only want them to be reachable only by me and two others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it's certainly going to be available to bitbucket employees. Not that they'll be actively peeking into your code, but posting anything code in a SasS will, by definition, mean that your private data will not be absolutely private -- and subject to their security breaches, if any, on top of yours.

Comment: thanks, I thought about that either. So, I won't put my database schema and db connectionStrings on my commits.

Answer (score 7):

Well, ... so far I haven't heard of any incidents with BitBucket. So, I would say they are as private and as secure as any other of the kind (CodePlex, GitHub, et cetera et cetera).

In the end, *as always*, it always comes down to how much resources someone has to break into your private repository, and how much resources you're willing to invest to protect it. But I doubt that is your scenario, so I wouldn't worry about that.

If you really wish to ask about some specifics you can for example, find one of the authors of BitBucket on [twitter Jesper Noehr](http://twitter.com/#!/jespern).